# Unable to update trigger code coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am unable to increase the code coverage of the trigger :

```
trigger PrimaryEmailUpdate on Contact (after update) {
    Map<id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<id, Account>();
    List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Contact con : trigger.new)  
    {
        if(con.Primary__c) 
            listIds.add(con.AccountID);
    }   
    parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT id, Primary_Contact_Email_c__c , primarycontactname__c  FROM Account WHERE ID IN :listIds]);

    for (Contact cont : Trigger.new){
        if(parentAccs != null && parentAccs.containsKey(Cont.AccountID))
        {
            Account myParentAcc = parentAccs.get(Cont.AccountID);
            myParentAcc.Primary_Contact_Email_c__c  = Cont.Email;
            String conName = '';
            if(cont.firstname != null && cont.firstname != '')
                conName = conName + cont.firstname;
            if(conName == '')
                conName = conName + cont.lastname;
            else 
                conName = conName +' ' +cont.lastname;
            myParentAcc.Primary_Contact_Email_c__c  = conName;
        }
    }
    if(parentAccs != null && parentAccs.size() >0 )
        update parentAccs.values();
}
```

from below test class further :

```
@istest
public class testemailUpdateTrigger
{
    static testMethod void test(){
        Account a = new Account(name='testing',Primary_Contact_Email_c__c ='test2',primarycontactname__c='test3');
        insert a;
        a.name='testing update';
        update a;

        contact c = new contact(AccountID=a.id ,FirstName='Mani',LastName='Test');
        insert c;
        c.FirstName='testing update';
        update c;


        Map<id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<id, Account>();
        List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

        listIds.add(c.AccountID);

        parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT id, Primary_Contact_Email_c__c , primarycontactname__c  FROM Account WHERE ID IN :listIds]);
        if(parentAccs != null && parentAccs.containsKey(c.AccountID))
        {
            Account myParentAcc = parentAccs.get(c.AccountID);
            myParentAcc.Primary_Contact_Email_c__c  = c.Email;
            String conName = '';
            if(c.firstname != null && c.firstname != '')
                conName = conName + c.firstname;
            if(conName == '')
                conName = conName + c.lastname;
            else 
                conName = conName +' ' +c.lastname;
            myParentAcc.Primary_Contact_Email_c__c  = conName;
        }

        if(parentAccs != null && parentAccs.size() >0 )
            update parentAccs.values();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current coverage?  Which lines aren't covered?

Comment: Already Done :) thnx

Comment: What do you mean by that?  I don't see those questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
@istest
public class testemailUpdateTrigger
{
 static testMethod void test(){
Account a = new Account(name='testing',Primary_Contact_Email_c__c ='test2',primarycontactname__c='test3');
insert a;
a.name='testing update';
update a;

contact c = new contact(AccountID=a.id ,FirstName='Mani',LastName='Test',Primary__c=true);
insert c;
c.FirstName='testing update';
update c;


    Map<id, Account> parentAccs = new Map<id, Account>();
            List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();
if(c.Primary__c) {
 listIds.add(a.id);
}                 
   parentAccs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT id, Primary_Contact_Email_c__c , primarycontactname__c  FROM Account WHERE ID IN :listIds]);
 if(parentAccs != null && parentAccs.containsKey(c.AccountID))
               {
                Account myParentAcc = parentAccs.get(c.AccountID);
                myParentAcc.Primary_Contact_Email_c__c  = c.Email;
                   String conName = '';
                   if(c.firstname != null && c.firstname != '')
                   conName = conName + c.firstname;
                 if(conName == '')
                   conName = conName + c.lastname;
                 else 
                   conName = conName +' ' +c.lastname;
                myParentAcc.Primary_Contact_Email_c__c  = conName;
                }

                 if(parentAccs != null && parentAccs.size() >0 )
          update parentAccs.values();

}
}
```

Comment: while replying to any answer always elaborate what is wrong with actual question and point out issue in code. It will help others to corelate their problem if they have.